# 404 File not found when using github pages to publish website

Tags: html, css, github

404
File not found

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL as well as any file permissions.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages.

This is the error I'm getting when trying to publish my website on github, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my repo https://github.com/colinms4/portfolio-website

Been trying to look for a fix but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since your HTML files are in `html/` in the repo root, they're available under the same subpath in your GitHub Pages root, i.e.

https://colinms4.github.io/portfolio-website/html/

If you want https://colinms4.github.io/portfolio-website/ to do the right thing, you'll need `index.html` to be in the repository root.